# Categorizing Posts in a Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, post, meteor, categories, tagging

I have a Meteor Collection called Posts as shown below:

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

I want to categorize them by a field I call "genre" and have different genre posts appear in different tabs in my navigation bar. I've tried installing tags for meteor and creating multiple Collections, but those attempts have not been successful.

Does anyone know how I can categorize one Posts collection (if possible) into multiple feeds on different tabs and sort them by time created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is pretty easy with meteor

You should first create and event handler like this if you don't know about event handlers or insert into collections take a look into [insert method on Mongo.Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) and event handlers [Meteor Events Handlers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events)

This is how a Event handler look on MeteorJs

```
template.navbar.events({
  'click #button':function(){
    Posts.insert({genre:"Rock"})
   }
 })
```

or if you want to skip the event handler (just for testing purposes) create a folder named `/Server` with a file inside name `testInsert.js` with this code

so our path look like this `/appName/server/testInsert.js`

```
if (Posts.find().count() === 0) {
  Posts.insert({
    genre: 'Rock',
  });

  Posts.insert({
    title: 'Music',
  });

  Posts.insert({
    title: 'Art',
  });
}
```

Now we need to show the Posts Data on the Meteor template, so we need a  [Meteor Template.helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)

```
Template.navbars.helpers({
  showGenre:function(){
   return Posts.find();
  }
})
```

And this is how we call that helper on the Template,Meteor uses the spacebars engine on the templates.

If you wanna take a deep look into `Spacebars` take a look into this [Understanding Spacebars](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/)

```
 <template name="navbars">
    {{#each showGenre}}
      <!-- navbar stuff go here -->
      {{genre}} <!-- here you are only calling genre field from Posts Collection -->
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

**GO Further**

run this commands to get some meteor apps examples.

```
meteor create --example todos or
meteor create --example localmarket
```

**OR** take a look into [this resources](https://www.meteor.com/learn) if you want to learn meteor more properly